# google play services lib... cannot import com.google.android.gms.map (using eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

i'm having some problem with the google play services library (using eclipse). Thus, I tried to do the following example  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro

But I still have multiple error for all the import below com.google.android.gms.maps for instance.

- I have the google-play-services_lib imported within my eclipse workspace
- In my project>properties>android>Library the google-play-services_lib is actually referenced
- its also referenced in java build path > libraries

Comment: don't do like that,have some problem in directly import the library.first copy that library to workspace then import it from workspace,it will work.

Comment: Thanks, i did import with copy files to workspace this time but it didn't solve my issue :/

Answer (score 1):

Try importing `yourAdtBundlePath/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib` as a project in Eclipse (I assume you use Eclipse) and then adding it as a library in `Properties for YourProject/Android/Library/Add...`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, actually i may have not been precise enough.
the google-play-services_lib is already a project and i reference it in my example project in project>android>library and also in java build path>libraries

Comment: it finally works but i dont really understand.
i deleted everything then reimport by copying files into eclipse, made sure that no references in java build path were made but only in the android>library references were made